# Example for Surfaceplotter 2.0.1?

Tags: java, charts, 3d

I was looking for a simple 3D chart without too many dependencies, and I found Surfaceplotter for Java. However, I can not seem to find one single tutorial or example.

Here is the link: [Surfaceplotter](https://code.google.com/archive/p/surfaceplotter/)

If anybody has any idea or can post a simple code - I would really appreciate it.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a small example at the developers' GitHub:
https://github.com/ericaro/surfaceplotter/tree/master/src/test/java

Comment: This is a link only answer - see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) - you could improve it by summarizing the example from github

Comment: @alexanderbird great job humiliating newcomer. This is the only answer. This answer is helpful. If you can improve answer - do so.